# IA 32 architecture segmentation

Tags: cpu, intel, architecture

I was reading the 10th edition of "Operating System Concepts" written by Abraham Silberschatz and many others. It says about IA-32 architecture's segmentation:

> The IA-32 architecture allows a segment to be as large as 4 GB, and the maximum number of segments per process is 16 K.

but I don't understand, we need 14 bits to determine the segment and the CPU is 32 bit so 18 bits left, Therefore the maximum accessing area is 256KB, not 4GB. Help me understand how we could manage 4GB here.

Comment: It does not mean these two are happening at the same time. So you can have one segment of 4GB or four off 1GB, or 16384 of 256KB, but also a mixture of segments e.g. one of 16MB and two of 256KB and the rest of the memory is not used by that process.

Comment: I understand what you mean but in the next paragraphs, he has drowned a figure for logical address and says the logical address is consists of a selector and offset. The selector is 16 bits and he specifies clearly offset is 32 bit!!! @Oldfart

Comment: The segment number is not part of the address. There is a 14 bit segment number and also a 32 bit address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the <strike>good</strike> old days of the 80286, the address space had 24 bits (16 MB), but registers still had 16 bits (64 KB). So you had a 16-bit selector, pointing to a segment descriptor containing the 24-bit base address of the segment, and a 16-bit offset into the segment. You needed multiple segment to access the entire address space.

With the 32-bit 80386, both the address space and the register size were enlarged to 32 bits. So now you have a 16-bit selector, pointing to a segment descriptor containing the 32-bit base address of the segment, and a 32-bit offset into the segment.

This means that IA-32 allows a single segment to cover the entire address space. And this is in fact how most operating systems work nowadays: they use a fixed segment with a base address of zero, and otherwise ignore segmentation.